# An item with the same key has already been added.Error when selecting all records

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

that's my DataBase model that im using in my Web Application
[image]
now all what i'm trying to do is to add new administrator or select all administrators but i get an error.

```
An item with the same key has already been added.
```

the code i use to select all administrator :

```
MyContext.Administrators.Where(a => a.IsActive ==true).ToList();
```

my code for adding a new administrator:

```
Administrators AdministratorsObj = new Administrators();
                AdministratorsObj.AdminFName = txtAdminFname.Text;
                AdministratorsObj.AdminLName = txtLastName.Text;
                AdministratorsObj.AdminLogInName = txtUserName.Text;
                AdministratorsObj.AdminPassword = txtPassword.Text;
                AdministratorsObj.AdminEmail = txtEmail.Text;
                AdministratorsObj.AdminHomePhone = txtPhone.Text;
                AdministratorsObj.AdminCellPhone = txtMobile.Text;
                AdministratorsObj.AdminType = chkIsSuperAdmin.Checked;
                AdministratorsObj.IsActive = chkIsActive.Checked;
                AdministratorsDALObj = new AdministratorsDAL();
                int AdminId = MyContext.AddAdministrators(AdministratorsObj);
```

AddAdministrators method code:

```
public int AddAdministrators(Administrators AdministratorsEnt)
{
    try
    {
        if (AdministratorsEnt == null)
            return -1;
        AdministratorsEnt.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
        AdministratorsEnt.DeleteStatusCode = false;
        MyContext.AddToAdministrators(AdministratorsEnt);
        if (MyContext.SaveChanges() > 0)
            return AdministratorsEnt.AdminId;
        return -1;

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        return -1;
    }
}
```

note that column AdminId in administrators table is Identity so that AdminId is auto-incremented.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure it's this line causing the error? What's your code for adding new administrators?

Comment: hi @Tieran i have updated my question. please look at it again.Thanks for your help

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but catching all exceptions will mask real bugs like NullRefExceptions. Just let the exception bubble up to someone who can really handle it.

Comment: What version of EF are you using? Isn't `.AddTo` depreciated?

Comment: Do you have any inheritance that is not being shown on the diagram. For example does Administrators inherit from users?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue in EF 4.1. with an existing application.
What happened? The EF 4.1 requires the .net framework 4.0. Windows update replaced the .net framework 4.0 with 4.5 and I got the same error you got.
The solution was to uninstall .net 4.5 and install .net 4.0.